# MySQL Kerberos authentication

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kerberos

I have a instance of MySql 8.0.16 hosted in AWS RDS environment.

I need to configure the MySql instance to authenticate against a Active Directory using Kerberos protocol. I followed all steps described in the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql-kerberos.html).

I have inserted an user using the SQL instruction below:

```
CREATE USER 'testuser@domain.com'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'auth_pam';
UPDATE mysql.user SET ssl_type = 'any' WHERE ssl_type = '' AND PLUGIN = 'auth_pam' and USER = 'testuser@domain.com';`
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

(username and domain names have been changed for privacy!)

The database instance was started without errors and I got the access thru the sql comand prompt and also with workbench. So far, everything perfect!

But here the problem started. The database will be accessed from a web application developd in Java-SpringBoot using the the ConectorJ provided by MySql team. I configured the datasource following the instructions present in the Spring documentation. I have changed only these lines:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database-server/testdb
spring.datasource.username=testuser@domain.com
spring.datasource.password=password #(domain password)
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

But when the container is starting, this error message appears in the logs:

```
2020-07-17 00:06:58.531  INFO 8016 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-07-17 00:06:59.578 ERROR 8016 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'dialog'.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:85) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'dialog'.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:490) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:171) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1342) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I've looked everywhere about this error and found no answers! I'll appreciate any tip to solve this trouble!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [This](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=829) might help.

Comment: Is the web application running on Windows or Linux?  If on Windows, is it joined to the domain?

Comment: @T-Heron the application is installed on windows. But I did 3 applications to test the database acces, one in C#, one in Python and another one in Java, and I got the same error.

Comment: Good to know.  There should be a Kerberos delegation in place for this kind of forwarding of authentication to MySQL to work, but I looked through the Amazon instructions you referenced and found no mention of that in that document.

Answer (score 0):

Hello to use PAM authentication you must use SSL to connect :

```
    6.10 Connecting Using PAM Authentication
Java applications using Connector/J can connect to MySQL servers that use the pluggable authentication module (PAM) authentication scheme.

For PAM authentication to work, you must have the following:

A MySQL server that supports PAM authentication. See PAM Pluggable Authentication for more information. Connector/J implements the same cleartext authentication method as in Client-Side Cleartext Pluggable Authentication.

SSL capability, as explained in Section 6.7, “Connecting Securely Using SSL”. Because the PAM authentication scheme sends the original password to the server, the connection to the server must be encrypted.

PAM authentication support is enabled by default in Connector/J 8.0, so no extra configuration is needed.

To disable the PAM authentication feature, specify mysql_clear_password (the method) or com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.authentication.MysqlClearPasswordPlugin (the class name) in the comma-separated list of arguments for the disabledAuthenticationPlugins connection option. See Section 6.3, “Configuration Properties” for details about that connection option.
```

I think you must use something like this :

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MySampleDb?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

And pass truststore and keystore parameters

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore_file
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path_to_truststore_file
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

Comment: The connections was done thru SSL, but I got the same error, with or without SSL.